# What is asm instruction "jmpq *0xa48201(%rip)" exactly doing?

Tags: gcc, assembly, gdb, x86-64

I'm stepping through assembly in gdb and I have the assembler instruction

```
0xbca5c50 <_bin_start+23632> jmpq   *0xa48201(%rip)        # 0xc6ede57

(gdb) x /32bx 0xbca5c50
0xbca5c50:      0xff    0x25    0x01    0x82    0xa4    0x00    0x68
```

and I wonder how the instruction is calculating its jump address.

```
(gdb) x /xg 0xc6ede57
0xc6ede57:      0x000000000933d070
```

`0xc6ede57` point to data `0x0933d070` and that address (?) seems to be also somehow
involved.

Can somebody describe how  `jmpq *addr(%rip)` works?

Is it right that the target jump address should actually be 0x933d070 ?

Comment: The jump address is loaded from memory.  It's a memory-indirect jump.

Comment: Also, if you are confused by at&t syntax, switch your tool to intel. In gdb you can do `set disassembly-flavor intel`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: What I see when doing stepi is  hat I jump to 0xbe4cc80, is the expected behaviour a jump to 0x933d070? (Btw: the answer in the question marked as duplicated seems not right - it doenst involve a indirection...)

Comment: In the linked duplicate it's also `jmpq *symbol(%rip)`, in that case indirection through the GOT.  Again, loading the target address from memory, using that addressing mode.  Read the manual for `jmp`.  http://felixcloutier.com/x86/JMP.html, and see other links in the x86 tag wiki.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: @PeterCordes: The actual instruction is: ```(gdb) x /32bx 0xbca5c50
0xbca5c50:      0xff    0x25    0x01    0x82    0xa4    0x00    0x68    0x2a```. Is it possible that this is some kind of ```call gate``` that involves segment registers?

Comment: So you set a breakpoint at jmp instruction, and examined memory right before it executed?   Yeah that's strange.  I don't think call gates work for `jmp`, only for `call`.  It's weird that your segment registers are all zero; what OS are you using?  On Linux, my CS is `0x33` and SS is `0x2b` when I set a breakpoint at `_start` in `/bin/ls`.  (And those don't change for the whole process.)  I don't think CS can use a null selector; it has to refer to a code segment in the GDT or LDT with the `L` bit set (so the CPU runs in 64-bit mode).

Comment: What are you debugging, and how?  Is it possible that the jmp faulted (or code-fetch from 0x0933d070 faulted) and you ended up in the signal handler for SIGSEGV or something?  `0xff    0x25    0x01    0x82    0xa4    0x00` is definitely a near jump, so no segments or call-gates are involved in any way.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks. I run a linux binary that is obfuscated on a S2E platform.The jump at 0xbca5c50 is the programs call into libc's malloc through the global object table at 0xc6ede57. I have enabled processor trace around the instruction and now I can see that there seems the be binary instrumentation taking place. I guess I cannot trust the output of gdb and need to dig into S2E. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your edit removed anything about your code actually jumping to a different address.  Was that intentional, so that this is just a simple duplicate asking what an indirect jump does?  If you wanted to turn it into a question about GDB on whatever test setup you're using, I can reopen this so you can post an answer that GDB can't follow whatever weirdness is going on even with `si`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I have removed the extra info because the original question was what "jmp *(rip)" actually does. That was a duplicate and therefore I choose to remove the noise. 
The actual problem is the binary instrumentation that I'm running in S2E that will rewrite malloc allocations. The gdb stub seems to skip that.

Comment: You mean this https://github.com/s2e?  I don't know anything about it.  Oh, but you say it provides a GDB remote you can connect to?  I guess you're then not debugging pure x86 anymore; you're debugging a machine that rewrites indirect jumps to some library calls!  This duplicate probably isn't useful (anyone searching should already find the dup target) so we could clean up the comments and edit it into your real question turned out to be.  Or just leave it.  Or post a new self-answered Q&A about how S2E doesn't behave like a real x86 here.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes. I'll just leave the issue.